# Mongoose no longer accepts a callback

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Good morning. I hope You are well.So i try finish some udemy course but i stuck with this code because mogoose no longer accepts callback function.I tried to change function to :"then"+".catch", but still not working.

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  Item.find({}, function (err, foundItems) {
    if (foundItems.length === 0) {
      Item.insertMany(defaultItems, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log("Successfully savevd default items to DB.");
        }
      });
      res.redirect("/");
    } else {
      res.render("list", { listTitle: "Today", newListItems: foundItems });
    }
  });
});
```

and error form terminal:
"MongooseError: Model.find() no longer accepts a callback"

Sorry to take up your time, I know you have better things to do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a callback, Monggose methods are now returning `Promise`s. So you should go for something like this

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  const foundItems = await Item.find({});
  if (foundItems.length === 0) {
      Item.insertMany(defaultItems).then(() => 
        console.log("Successfully saved default items to DB."))
        .catch((err) =>  console.log(err));
      res.redirect("/");
    } else {
      res.render("list", { listTitle: "Today", newListItems: 
      foundItems });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new here..sorry if not a good enough answer...but

You're gonna have to use the async/await focntionnality...

You have to enclose :

```js
Item.find({}, function (err, foundItems) {
    if (foundItems.length === 0) {
      Item.insertMany(defaultItems, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log("Successfully savevd default items to DB.");
        }
      });
      res.redirect("/");
    } else {
      res.render("list", { listTitle: "Today", newListItems: foundItems });
    }
  });
```

in a async fonction... and call it with await.

Here is an example of my code :

```js
    
export async function getPublicBottles(): Promise<bottle[]> {
    
    const bottles = await Bottle.find({userTargetName:"PublicBottle"});
    if (!bottles) {
        console.warn("[DATA] No users in database.");
        throw createError(httpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "No bottles found");
    }

    return bottles;
}
```

then you call :

```js
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  const data = await getPublicBottles();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Heyy, i'm taking the same course and that's how i did it :

```js
app.get("/", function (req, res) {

    async function myitems() {
        const foundItems = await Item.find({});
        
        if (foundItems.length === 0) {
        
            Item.insertMany(defaultItems);
            res.redirect("/");
            
        } else {
            res.render("list", { listTitle: "Today", listItems: foundItems });
        }
    }
    myitems();
});
```

in newer version of moongose a couple of things are different.
`await MyModel.find({});` needs to be inside a async function in order to work I called it `myitems()` like in the snippet above.

Comment: oh if you're gonna copy be careful cause my namings can be different from you, for example i use listItems instead of newListItems